# QVideoWidget no video

Tags: qt

I am doing project on Qt 5.2 with display video. I had a problem with displaying, no movie but sound still works well. Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QMediaPlaylist>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMediaObject>
#include <QtMultimedia>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWidget* widget = new QWidget();

    player = new QMediaPlayer;
    QMediaPlaylist* m_playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/storage/emulated/0/Bluetooth/video1.mp4"));

    m_widgetVideo = new QVideoWidget(widget);
    player->setVideoOutput(m_widgetVideo);

    setCentralWidget(widget);
    widget->show();
    m_playlist->setCurrentIndex(0);
    player->play();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
     delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux: sudo apt-get install gst123 (install GStreamer dependencies)
Window: install LAV Filters (install DirectShow Media Decoders)

Comment: explain your answer please